# Integrability and Lebesgue Measure for Countable Discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I ran into two results that seemed to conflict with each other, but I'm sure that I'm just misunderstanding something.

This is my first analysis course, but based on this construction, I'm sure that this is somewhat of a "classic" problem that the book discusses: define f(x) = 1 if x is rational, 0 if irrational defined on the closed interval [a,b].

Result 1: f is not Riemann integrable on [a,b]
Result 2: g is Riemann integrable on [a,b] if and only if {x in [a,b]: g is discontinuous} has content 0
and I also found a result that a countably infinite set has content 0

So from Result 2, can I not conclude that f(x) is integrable? Or is there a subtle detail in one of the hypotheses that I'm missing? Or does the fact that the set of all rationals is dense in the reals somehow lead to the discontinuities being uncountably infinite?

Answer (score 1):

Your function is discontinuous at every irrational number (because you can find rationals arbitrarily close to it, ...), and every rational number (ditto irrationals arbitrarily close) so the set of discontinuities is actually the whole of $[0,1]$, which certainly doesn't have measure zero.

Contrast with the function
$$ g(x) = \begin{cases}
1/q & x = p/q, \quad p,q \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } (p,q)=1 \\
0 & x \in \mathbb{R \setminus Q}
\end{cases}, $$
which is only discontinous at the rationals and so is integrable.